# jquery autocomplete for multiple textboxes inside asp.net Gridview

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have asp.net `Gridview` that have at least 15 rows with textbox by default example

[image]

**aspx**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_Others" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="gvothers">
                    <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField >                        
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                        <ItemTemplate >                     
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmp" runat="server" Width=100% Height=22px CssClass="txtE"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

aspx.cs (here how I am generating 15 rows of a `GridView`)

```
private void SetInitialRowsofOthers()
    {
        var list = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            list.Add(string.Empty);
        }
        gv_Others.DataSource = list;
        gv_Others.DataBind();
        gv_Others.HeaderRow.Visible = false;

     }
```

**WevService.axms**

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public List<string> GetotherServices(string txt1)
    {
        // your code to query the database goes here
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        string QueryString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["autoDBConn"].ToString();

        using (SqlConnection obj_SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(QueryString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand obj_Sqlcommand = new SqlCommand("Select DISTINCT OtherService as txt1 from easy_tblOtherServiceMaster where OtherService like @SearchText + '%' ", obj_SqlConnection))
            {
                obj_SqlConnection.Open();
                obj_Sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", txt1);
                SqlDataReader obj_result1 = obj_Sqlcommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (obj_result1.Read())
                {
                    result.Add(obj_result1["txt1"].ToString().TrimEnd());
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I want to fill each textbox by jQuery `autocomplete`.. for this I created a webservice and getting a value from jQuery.

How I am trying to achieve this task:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    SearchText();
                    function SearchText() {
                        var $arrT = $('#<%=gv_Others.ClientID %>').find('input:text[id$="txtEmp"]');
                        $($arrT).autocomplete({
                            source: function(request, response) {
                                $.ajax({
                                url: "WebService.asmx/GetotherServices",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                    data: "{ 'txt1' : '" + $($arrT).val() + "'}",
                                    dataFilter: function(data) { return data; },
                                    success: function(data) {
                                        response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
                                            return {
                                                label: item,
                                                value: item
                                            }
                                        }))
                                        //debugger;
                                    },
                                    error: function(result) {
                                        alert("Error");
                                    }
                                });
                            },
                            minLength: 1,
                            delay: 1000
                        });
                    }
                });
        </script>

          <script type="text/javascript">
              $(document).ready(function() {

                  SearchText();

                  function SearchText() {
                      $("#<%=Txt_RegNo.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
                          source: function(request, response) {
                              $.ajax({
                              url: "WebService.asmx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                                  type: "POST",
                                  dataType: "json",
                                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                  data: "{ 'txt' : '" + $("#<%=Txt_RegNo.ClientID %>").val() + "'}",
                                  dataFilter: function(data) { return data; },
                                  success: function(data) {
                                      response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
                                          return {
                                              label: item,
                                              value: item
                                          }
                                      }))
                                      //debugger;
                                  },
                                  error: function(result) {
                                      alert("Error");
                                  }
                              });
                          },
                          minLength: 1,
                          delay: 1000
                      });
                  }
              });
        </script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {  
                    $('input:text:first').focus();
                    var $inp = $('input:text');
                    $inp.bind('keydown', function(e) {
                        //var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode);
                        var key = e.which;
                        if (key == 13) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            var nxtIdx = $inp.index(this) + 1;
                            $(":input:text:eq(" + nxtIdx + ")").focus();
                        }
                    });
                });
                </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function Load_OtherService() {
                    var hv = $('input[id$=hdnOthers]');
                    var $arrT = $('#<%=gv_Others.ClientID %>').find('input:text[id$="txtEmp"]');  
                    var hv1 = "" + hv.val();
                    var va = hv1.split(',');
                    for (var j = 0; j < va.length; j++) {
                        var $txt = $arrT[j];
                        $($txt).val(va[j]);
                    }                          
                }
            </script>
```

Now for example when I type "Engine Work" in TEXTBOX 1 and select the value which populated by jQuery `autocomplete`("Engine Work") then second time when I type in other text box (TEXT BOX 2). It's only give me the "Engine Work" option to select.. which means after selecting any value (populated by jQuery `autocomplete`) I can't select any other value in other text boxes....
Example:- (See Image Below)

[image]

as you see i type Genral Work but still it`s populating the Previous value "Engine Work" in jquery AutoComplete which i dont want

How to find the TextBox by CSS Class using jQuery????

Something like this (its only find TextBox id by using jQuery inside `GridView` but I need to find textbox by Css Class)

```
var $arrT = $('#<%=gv_Others.ClientID %>').find('input:text[id$="txtEmp"]');
```

Comment: Thanks for updating the question.  Sometimes my eyes read "What's 1 + 1?" and my mind interprets it as "What's the capital of Nebraska?"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your script block to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // This selects all inputs inside the table with the txtE class and applies
    // the autocomplete function to them
    $('table[id$="gv_Others"] input.txtE').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "WebService.asmx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "{ 'txt1' : '" + request.term + "'}", 
                dataFilter: function(data) { return data; },
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
                        return {
                            label: item,
                            value: item
                        }
                    }))
                    //debugger;
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        delay: 1000
    });
});
```

Look at the `data:` in the ajax post - it's using `request.term` and I changed the selector.

The issue with your jquery is this line:

```
data: "{ 'txt1' : '" + $($arrT).val() + "'}",
```

That will always return the first value of the array (the first textbox) so it's always submitting the first value to your webservice as the search text.

Comment: hi @Zach i have tried this, before your answer... it`s also populating the previous selected value in other textboxes

Comment: Ok then you want to use a filter expression and filter where val() == ''

Comment: @zech if it`s possible by using filter expression then why not

Comment: The value of the first text box was always submitted to your webservice.  This is because you're passing $($arrT).val() to the $.ajax POST.

Comment: @zech Thank for givning me valueable time it`s solved my problem

Comment: hi @zech i am getting this error
TypeError: elem.nodeName is undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55147/discussion-between-zach-and-siddiq-baig).

Comment: I don't think you need the .each(function(){}) anymore.  You can try it without that now.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace PlatForm_RollUp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for SearchDPN
    /// </summary>
    public class SearchDPN : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string prefixText = context.Request.QueryString["term"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefixText)) { prefixText = "NA"; }
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
                        .ConnectionStrings["PPN_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "select DPN_Key, DPN, Item_Desc from Customer.DIM.PPN WHERE " +
                        "DPN like @SearchText+'%'";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    List<string> _dpn = new List<string>();
                    conn.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            //sb.Append(string.Format("{0} - {1}", sdr["DPN"], sdr["Item_Desc"], Environment.NewLine));
                            _dpn.Add(sdr["DPN"].ToString() +" - " +sdr["Item_Desc"].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                    context.Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(_dpn));
                }
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}


***************************
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />      
         <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                initializer();
            });
            var prmInstance = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
            prmInstance.add_endRequest(function () {
                //you need to re-bind your jquery events here
                initializer();
            });
            function initializer() {

                $("[id*=txtDPN]").autocomplete({ source: 
                   "/Handlers/SearchDPN.ashx" });
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: I used Asp.Net Generic handler executing the SQL with the Text entered is passed as parameter to the SQL Command. It returns the response to autocomplete the textbox where the text is entered.